Changing ContentView's source programatically causes memory leaks
In my MAUI mobile app I have a page with a ContentView. I need to be able to swap the content out many times.  But each view I'm using isn't being garbage collected after being shown and then replaced by another view, so the app eventually fails due to memory issues.
Am I going about being able to swap out a subview incorrectly?
The code demonstrates a simplified version of what I'm trying to do.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ViewSwapTest.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Padding="30,0"
            Spacing="25">
            
            <ContentView
                x:Name="ContentView"
                HeightRequest="100"
                WidthRequest="100" />
            
            <Button
                x:Name="Button1"
                Text="1" 
                Clicked="OnButton1Hit"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
            <Button
                x:Name="Button2"
                Text="2" 
                Clicked="OnButton2Hit"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private View lastView;
    
    private void OnButton1Hit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lastView = null;
        lastView = new BlueView();
        ContentView.Content = lastView;
    }
    private void OnButton2Hit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lastView = null;
        lastView = new RedView();
        ContentView.Content = lastView;
    }
}


You include RedView and BlueView in your minimal example. Do we know in advance what the names of all the (real) views will be?

How do you know garbage collection is not working and that you are leaking memory? Note that garbage collection will not happen immediately and just because you reassign lastView. The garbage collector optimizing engine determines the best time to perform a collection based on allocations being made. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals

You can try to use the single instance mode for the two views. Creating new instance of the view frequently will cause memory leak easily.
